# webkit zoom bug scaling issue with font size, doesn't seem to get smaller

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit

i have an issue with webkit browsers safari and chrome. when i zoom out, i have a line of text set at 41px, and another font set at about 12px. when i zoom out to around 33% and 25%, the font set at 12px doesn't get smaller. in fact it is almost the same size as the 41 px text, so because of this when i zoom out in webkit, the text that doesn't get smaller overflows their container, and spills out, pushing other text out of their container and so on.  this only happens in webkit browsers, it works perfect in firefox, ie, and opera.

i have looked over the internet to find anything but i only found one website talking about the font-size threshold in google chrome: http://dropshado.ws/post/12971305087/webkit-zoomed-out-font-size-threshold

i couldn't find a bugzilla bug that was specific to this problem. the only solution i found was to specify overflow hidden on the divs containing overflowing text, and it looks fine, but the font is still not scaled right, and is just cut off. anyone else experience this?

Comment: yes. webkit's zoom is still buggy.. And its their big architectural issue (but which they are planning to solve: http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/ScalesAndZooms). To avoid problems - make your layout more "defensive", so it can survive small rounding errors.

Comment: how can you make the layout more defensive? can you explain?

Comment: bigger width/height, overflow:hidden, no pixel-tight layouts based on floats/inline-blocks, anticipating word-wrap issues and so on. Usual boring stuff, no silver bullet.